# How to identify slow-running SQL Server reportng ssrs reports

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, query-performance

I want to list all the reports that run slow so I can review the SQL code to see if any performance improvements can be made.

On the ReportServer database I have the executionlog table, which columns will help me identify where the bottlenecks are?

I have TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing, TimeRendering - How can I use these to help me improve performance?

Comment: To identify bad-performing queries I wouldn't bother with this at all, use Querystore or some of the various amazing community tools (Google SP Blitzcache) to analyze the SQL Server plan cache for the most resource consuming queries.

Comment: Firstly I need to know which reports are running slow, we have hundreds. I'll then go about looking at the SQL.

Comment: TimeDataRetrieval will tell you how long it took to get the data from the database but without any context it's not going to tell you much more. If a report is querying 1 million records and takes 10 seconds that might be fine but then a report that queries 100 records and takes 2 seconds and is also run 100 times a day could be performing badly.

Comment: Ask the users or your QA group. Make them happy.

Comment: There has to be a more technical way with stats

Comment: *There has to be a more technical way with stats* yes the SQ: Server DMVs have plenty of them.